# Pip install binary and preserve requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I'm making a Python package dependent on `spacy`. Spacy works with binary language models. So I have the URLs listed at the end of my `requirements.txt`

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=spacy-english-model
```

But if I `freeze` the environment the package does not appear with the URL for download:

```
spacy-english-model==2.0.0
```

So if I add a package I can't `pip install` it and then `pip freeze`. How can specify the package in `requirements.txt` so that its URL shows up when `freeze`ing?

Comment: what would you need the pip freeze output in?

Comment: @mostafazh I need it so I can dsitribute my package with its code. I want to clone the repo, do `pip -r requirements.txt` and run it. Without the bibary packages It cannot run, so I have to download them in a separate step , which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `pip freeze` to distribute your package. When writing a package you'll need to add the models in your `requirements.txt` file, according to the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip) like so:

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0/es_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

you can see that happened [here](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) (check the `dev-requirements.txt`)

I don't know where did `pip freeze` get the `spacy-english-model` from. I'd start with a new python virtualenv and test everything again.

Comment: I understand, but my package is still under development, so I might add, in the future, more packages. With regular packages, the usual thing I do is just `pip install` new packages, and then in the end `pip freeze` to get the new list of packages. The problem is that the binary packages do not appear with their URLs, so I must look up the URL manually, which is quite annoying.